# Scala Object Usage

Tags: scala

Is it possible in scala to expose the functionality of a class, based on the condition?

Say

```
class c(a: Int, b: Int){
  if(a == 1){
     val variable: Int = a
     def function: Int = b
  }
```

Need to expose variable and function only when a is 1 during the usage of class

Comment: Assume for a moment that this would be somewhat possible. Now imagine I write a function that takes an instance of `c`, inside that function how would I know that I can _(or can't)_ use either `variable` or `function`? I expect that explains why this won't be useful. - Now, why do you want this? What is your use case? What is the bigger picture? Probably there are ways to model what you want to express.

Comment: The use case is c is being used for two different cases if a == 1 then it is being used for some functionality and else it is used for some different functionality, The thing is c cannot exhibit both the functionalities.

Comment: Why not just have two different classes? Why it has to be the same class? Again, how would you use such a class if it is different due a runtime information.

Comment: The structure/composition of `class C` is a compile-time property. The value of `a` (1, -2, 37, whatever) is a run-time property. "...and never the twain shall meet" -Kipling.

Answer (score 2):

No, members must be known at compile time so that access to members can be checked by the compiler.

One option is to use `Option`:

```
class c(a: Int, b: Int){
  val variable = if (a==1) Some(a) else None
  def function() = if (a==1) Some(f(b)) else None
}
```

You can use `variable.getOrElse(default)` to extract `variable` from an instance of `c`.

Another option is to use a class hierarchy

```
trait C

class B() extends C

class A(a: Int, b: Int) extends C {
  val variable: Int = a
  def function: Int = b
}

object C {
  def apply(a: Int, b: Int): C =
    if (a == 1) {
      new A(a, b)
    } else {
      new B()
    }
}
```

You create the instance with `C(...,...)` and when you need to access `variable` you use `match` to check that you have an instance of `A` rather than `B`.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible with dynamic loading, but there are very few use cases where this would be the right solution.

Many languages support dynamic loading actual modification of the byte code at run-time. The main use-case is to upgrade and modifying applications that cannot stop or cannot be redeployed.